# Quiz App force close

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I'm trying to make a quiz app. I got the code from a youtube video I have watched. I copied exactly what he did it works fine for her when he run it but in my case the app force close when I try to press next question... The first question appears and when I press enter then it force closes. Please help me, it's for my thesis.

here is the logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.intercode.triviaquiz.Quiz$1.onClick(Quiz.java:50)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18031)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code

```
package org.intercode.triviaquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Quiz extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvquestion;
    Button button;
    RadioGroup rg;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;

    String questions[]={"First Android Phone?", "Name of android version4.4?", "Android is which kind of software"};
    String ans[]={"Motorola Droid","KitKat","Operating System"};
    String opt[]={"HTC-G1", "HTC-One", "Motorola Droid", "JellyBean", "Froyo", "KitKat", "Operating System", "AntiVirus", "Application"};

    int flag=0;
    public static int marks, correct, wrong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tvquestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvquestion);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
        rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb2);
        rb3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb3);

        tvquestion.setText(questions[flag]);
        rb1.setText(opt[0]);
        rb2.setText(opt[1]);
        rb3.setText(opt[2]);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioButton uans = (RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
                if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(ans[flag]))
                {
                    correct++;
                }
                else
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
                flag++;
                if (flag < questions.length)
                {
                    tvquestion.setText(questions[flag]);
                    rb1.setText(opt[flag * 3]);
                    rb2.setText(opt[flag * 3]);
                    rb3.setText(opt[flag * 3]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Main.tbflag)
                    {
                        marks = correct - wrong;
                    } else
                    {
                        marks = correct;
                    }
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Results.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: would you mind posting your logcat?

Comment: what is at `Quiz.java:50`

Comment: i hope u guys can figure it out

Comment: Sure we will, answer @RRR question, what line is at number 50 at your Quit.java file?

Comment: its RadioButton uans = (RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

Comment: Okay, it's a null pointer exception, most probably because your **rg** (RadioGroup) is null. Can you check if you are using the correct ID when getting the radio group (findViewById)?

Comment: lol ya i didnt put name on my radiogroup i name it as rg and it works now but i have to work on the radio buttons coz when i press next the choices in the radio buttons are the same :P

Comment: lol dude u helped me so much its my first time using android studio i didnt even know whats in that logcat now i know now :D ur amazing

Comment: 1st question is fine 2nd question display only jelly bean in all 3 radio buttons and the 3rd question display only operating system in all radio buttons now

Comment: Probably because of the lines where you are setting the new answers (`flag * 3`). This is wrong, you probably want to increment the value for every answer. For first (`flag * 3`), second (`(flag * 3) + 1`) and third (`(flag * 3) + 2)`

Comment: thanks bro! lol in the youtube video i watched its was just written as (flag * 3) -.- idk how it works for him

Answer (score 1):

After LogCat

**First problem** was that the, RadioGroup was initialized with wrong resource id, and was null, so when calling `rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` there was a NullPointerException.

**Second problem** is the use of wrong `Context` when starting the Activity.

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Results.class);
```

The parameter `getApplicationContext()` is wrong, the intent should be tied to a `Context` of the `Activity`, not the `Application`.

Replace it with

```
Intent in = new Intent(Quiz.this, Results.class);
```

Comment: alright ill post the log sry

Comment: you can not pass `this` in `onClickListener`, it will take reference of current view

Comment: @RRR true, will fix the mistake. Thanks

Comment: ill try to replace it :P hope it would work

Comment: sir i had put the logcats up top also changin the getapplicationcontext to quiz.this wont solve the problem it still force close